# Why my append function is not showing output?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, insertion

I'm using this append function to append data on my linked-list but it's not showing any output. I've reviewed the code multiple times. This code worked in my previous code.

```
void append(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
/* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  /* used in step 5*/

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;

    /* 3. This new node is going to be the last node, so make next
          of it as NULL*/
    new_node->next = NULL;

    /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head */
    if (*head_ref == NULL)
    {
       *head_ref = new_node;
       return;
    }

    /* 5. Else traverse till the last node */
    while (last->next!= NULL)
        last = last->next;

    /* 6. Change the next of last node */
    last->next = new_node;
    return;
}

void printList(struct Node *node)
{
while(node->next!=NULL)
{
printf("%d ",node->data);
node = node->next;
}
}

int main()
{
struct Node *head = NULL;

push(&head,7);
push(&head,1);
push(&head, 3);
push(&head, 2);
append(&head,5);

puts("Created Linked List: ");
printList(head);
//deleteNode(&head, 1);
puts("\nLinked List after Deletion of 1: ");
printList(head);
return 0;
}
```

It's giving output:
**2->3->1->7**
Although I need output:
**2->3->1->7->5**

> Should I make the changes in linked list management?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. DId you also debug your code?

Comment: OT: regarding: `struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing the cast.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc()`, `calloc()` and/or `realloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "my error message" ); to output both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is just on printing out in `printList()`:

```
while(node->next!=NULL)
```

The very last node has the value `5` and `node->next == NULL`, so the loop will terminate without printing. Simply change to:

```
while(node != NULL)
```